# How to download a file from Mozilla Firefox using HTML?

Tags: python, html, firefox, safari

My task is, if user clicks download link to download a file, the file should be automatically downloaded. I done this task and got successful output in browsers chrome and IE.Now my problem is, my code is not working for browsers mozilla firefox and safari. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
ff = open('sample.html','a')
ms = """<h2>PRODUCT SUMMARY</h2>
<center><table border = "1">
<tr>
    <th>PRODUCT ID</th>
    <th>PRODUCT DOWNLOAD</th>
</tr>"""
ff.write(ms)
for row in __builtin__.product_info:
    ff.write("<tr>")
    ff.write("<td> %s</td>" %str(row[0]).strip())
    ff.write("<td>")
    ff.write("<a href= '%s' download>Download</a>" %str(row[1]).strip()) #(The problem is here..)
    ff.write("</td>")
    ff.write("</tr>")

m = """</center></table>
<br>
</pre>
</body>
</html>"""
ff.write(m)
ff.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create download link using this HTML tag:

```
<a href="link/to/file" download>Download link</a>
```

Comment: Bartosz, thanks for your reply. The same download attribute i used but still i dint get the output. This is working in chrome and IE .But fails in firefox and safari.Help me .

Comment: I wish I could but I have no clue what is this ff.write etc stuff about and why wont it work on Firefox or Safari, sorry mate.

Answer (score 0):

In MAC OS, if you want to download a file in browsers safari, chrome and mozilla firefox using HTML, use the below code. All these browsers download all files if it is compressed(.zip).

```
 <a href = "file:///Users/Shared/product_info.zip" download>Click to download</a>
```